# How do I turn on live window resizing in Ubuntu 10.10?

Tags: gnome, window, ubuntu-10.10

I've just installed Ubuntu 10.10. When I resize a window, it doesn't actually resize the window, just a semitransparent box, then the window snaps to the new size. How can I turn live window resizing on? I haven't seen this absurd behavior since Mac OS 9, and it's driving me nuts.

I've googled around using as many search terms as I can come up with to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Easiest way would be to install CCSM, via:

sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager

You can then find it in Menu -> System -> Preferences -> CompizConfig Settings Manager. See Window Management -> Resize Windows, tab General, first option.

If you don't see a difference, try Menu -> System -> Preferences -> Appearance, tab System Effects: put it on "Normal" or "Extra". That way, Compiz is used as a window manager instead of Metacity, I believe.

I've just installed Ubuntu a few days ago myself, and it's the first thing I changed, too.

Answer (score 2):

If using the Compiz window manager, open Compiz Settings Manager (package `compizconfig-settings-manager`), click on the *Resize Window* plugin, and select the *Normal* mode.

Comment: Live resizing in GTK2 programs can be slow at times. I just tried with an _empty_ `gedit` window and it only updated like every second, while `transmission-gtk` would constantly lose its window decorations while resizing. In comparison, Windows (XP and earlier) does it really smoothly, even if I have a lot of CPU-eating software running.

Comment: This isn't an issue in Fedora 14 or in earlier versions of Ubuntu - they all had live resizing out of the box.